# How to get sorted (x, y) coordinates by x from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my file looks like this.

```
2,3
44,13
3,4
```

And my code looks like this.

```
x = []
y = []  
with open('example.txt','r') as csvfile:
      plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
      for row in plots:
           x.append(int(row[0]))
           y.append(int(row[1]))
```

I need coordinates to load like this:

```
2,3 
3,4
44,13
```

How i can achieve it?
I tried something like this but it doesn't work :(

```
x = []
y = []

with open('test.txt','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        for row in sorted(plots, key=itemgetter(0)):
            x.append(int(row[0]))
            y.append(int(row[1]))
```

Comment: What does _it doesn't work_ mean, exactly?

Comment: It doesn't load sorted coordidnates

Comment: Well your code doesn't write the output to a file, so that is to be expected. I wrote an answer, if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused by the constant zipping/unzipping suggested in the accepted answer, it's entirely unnecessary.

```py
import csv

with open('../resources/temp_in.csv', newline='') as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    sorted_data = sorted((int(v_1), int(v_2)) for v_1, v_2 in reader)

with open('../resources/temp_in.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerows(sorted_data)
```

Note that I open/close the same file twice. It's possible to do so only once, but I find this to be more versatile.

Comment: doesn't this sort as strings since csv.reader won't convert to integers automatically?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Indeed it does, I don't know how I forgot that OP wants to compare the **numbers** themselves...

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` them together and then use `sorted`:

```
coordinates = sorted(zip(x, y))
```

In case you need to unpack back to `x, y` you can use `zip` again:

```
x, y = zip(*coordinates)
```